# jQuery slideToggle("slow") does not toggle at a slow speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery code that is using `slideToggle("slow")`.  The problem is that the "slow" effect does not work. There is absolutely no difference in behavior when I change from slow to fast or when I pass 200 to `slideToggle` compared to 800.  See the code in the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log("ready to go");
  $("#recordTable tr[data-cost-level='total']").click(
    function(evt) {
      // List the rows that need to be toggles
      var sourceData = 'division';
      var toggleData = 'cost-level';
      var toggleDataVal = 'subtotal';
      var sourceDataVal = $(this).data("division")
      $(this).siblings("[data-" + sourceData + "=" + sourceDataVal + "][data-" + toggleData + "=" + toggleDataVal + "]").slideToggle("slow");

      //toggleSubRows(evt, sourceData, toggleData, toggleDataVal) ;
      //console.log("Click even detected on", $(this));
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
  );

  var total = 0;


});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="recordTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item1" data-cost-type="cost_type1" data-cost-level="total" data-cost-category="expense" data-division="item1">
      <th colspan="4" class="title-row-light">
        <span class="item1_title">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down padding-right-2rem"></i> item1 
        </span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="2" class="title-row-light subtotal">
        <span class="item1_subtotal" data-type="category_subtotal"></span>
      </th>

    </tr>

    <tr class="grouping_item1" id="item1_3053" data-cost-type="cost_type1" data-cost-level="subtotal" data-cost-category="expense" data-division="item1">
      <td class="item2_type">
        <span class="item2_type" id="3053_item2_type" data-type=item_item2_type data-category="expense">WRMS</span>
      </td>
      <td class="costcode">
        <span class="costcode" id="3053_costcode" data-type=item_costcode data-category="expense">27.0.0 item1
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="rate">
        <span class="rate" id="3053_rate" data-type=item_rate data-category="expense">250.00 $/part</span>
      </td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <span class="quantity" id="3053_quantity"> 20,844.00 </span>
      </td>

      <td class="sub_total"> <span class="sub_total" id="3053_sub_total" data-type=item_sub_total data-category="expense"> 5211000.0000 </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="grouping_item1" id="item1_3053" data-cost-type="cost_type1" data-cost-level="subtotal" data-cost-category="expense" data-division="item1">
      <td class="item2_type">
        <span class="item2_type" id="3053_item2_type" data-type=item_item2_type data-category="expense">WRMS</span>
      </td>
      <td class="costcode">
        <span class="costcode" id="3053_costcode" data-type=item_costcode data-category="expense">27.0.0 item1
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="rate">
        <span class="rate" id="3053_rate" data-type=item_rate data-category="expense">250.00 $/part</span>
      </td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <span class="quantity" id="3053_quantity"> 20,844.00 </span>
      </td>

      <td class="sub_total"> <span class="sub_total" id="3053_sub_total" data-type=item_sub_total data-category="expense"> 5211000.0000 </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="grouping_item1" id="item1_3053" data-cost-type="cost_type1" data-cost-level="subtotal" data-cost-category="expense" data-division="item1">
      <td class="item2_type">
        <span class="item2_type" id="3053_item2_type" data-type=item_item2_type data-category="expense">WRMS</span>
      </td>
      <td class="costcode">
        <span class="costcode" id="3053_costcode" data-type=item_costcode data-category="expense">27.0.0 item1
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="rate">
        <span class="rate" id="3053_rate" data-type=item_rate data-category="expense">250.00 $/part</span>
      </td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <span class="quantity" id="3053_quantity"> 20,844.00 </span>
      </td>

      <td class="sub_total"> <span class="sub_total" id="3053_sub_total" data-type=item_sub_total data-category="expense"> 5211000.0000 </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Note that I was including (using Django templating language):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.js' %}"></script>
```

Then, to upgrade, I changed it to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

My question is why is the slideToggle speed not working and how to fix it?
P.s. I don't think down-voting is a particularly helpful feature. People with problems are motivated enough to resolve the issue if you explained what you need to be able to help (in this case the snippet). I do appreciate your time though

Comment: You're saying your problem is with a call to `slideToggle("slow")`, unless I'm missing something I don't see this call in the sample code you've posted. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you @esqew. Please see the added code

Comment: We don't need the `<head>` html. Please include the html this code is targeting.

Comment: @EarlyCoder, consider actually reading the link provided by esqew. So far, your example is only minimal. It's not reproducible. The article linked outlines how to go about creating a snippet which actually increases your chances of: **a)** finding the issue yourself; **b)** helping others understand/experience the bug, so they could help, in case ***"a)"*** does not happen while you're creating the example. A runnable snippet is very important for future users, to understand if the answer(s) might help them or not. Helping you ***and*** future users is main reason for answering.

Answer (score 0):

slideToggle(56); use time not string. or use integer variable with numbers.